# App unable to run on iPod touch

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to build an app onto a 4th gen iPod Touch and I'm getting a "failed to launch - failed to get task for process 346" error every time. I am able to build it onto both an iPad and iPhone, just not the iPod touch.

What happens is that it tries to run it, but the screen goes black with the spinning indicator, and the iPod itself appears to do a soft restart, as in it goes back to the lock screen.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens if you attempt to install a development build over the top of an ad hoc build.  Remove the app from your device and try again.  Failing that, reboot the device and your machine.

Comment: Tried all of the above, and still not working. Edited question with what is happening when it tries to run

Answer (score 0):

In your Entitlements.plist, check get-task-allow is set to true for debugging.

Apple [Technical Q&A QA1682](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1682/_index.html) offer a full explanation.